# WPF DatePicker DisplayDate binding does not work inside DataGrid/DataTemplate/ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker, datatemplate, controltemplate

It seems wpf DatePicker's DisplayDate binding does not work when datepiceker is inside datagrid or datatemplate.

Here is the sample code

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="StartDate" MinWidth="155">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=StartDate}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EndDate" MinWidth="155">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=EndDate}" DisplayDate="{Binding Path=StartDate}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

public class Model
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Display date is stuck to current date. No matter what the start date is.
I tried setting binding mode etc but it did not work.
What could be wrong?

Note: Although it does not matter for initial binding, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1291078

```
  <DatePicker DisplayDate={Binding Path=DisplayDate} Loaded="DatePicker_Loaded" />
```

and add to the code:

```
 private void DatePicker_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
             DatePicker dp = sender as DatePicker;
             if (dp != null)
             {
                     dp.ClearValue(DatePicker.DisplayDateProperty);
             }
 }
```